# Correct usage of »übrigbleiben«?

Tags: usage, verb-usage

What is a normal/common way of using the verb *übrigbleiben*? Does it make sense to use it like this:

> Gibt es Milch, die übrig geblieben ist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Gibt es Milch, die übrig geblieben ist?

is grammatical but I would rather put it this way:

> Ist (noch) Milch übrig geblieben?

You probably wanted to use "gibt es" from the English "is there".

This is also how German/Austrian children translate "is there/there is" when they start learning English. However, it is considered not a nice way to put it but a proper translation would have to be found for every usage of "is there/there is".

In the case of "übrig bleiben" (remaining) this would be

> - Ist Milch übrig geblieben?
> - Milch ist übrig geblieben.
> - Es ist keine Milch übrig geblieben.

Comment: "Gibt es noch Milch" would be equally fine. I'd say that "Gibt es noch" is just another phrase to say "ist noch übrig".

Comment: Ja genau, sehe ich auch so. Aber "gibt es" zusätzlich zu "übrig bleiben" ist irgendwie zu viel des Guten.

Comment: Umgangssprachlich würde ich den Satz noch abkürzen "Ist noch Milch übrig?" Wäre im englischen denke ich "Is there any milk left?" den entsprechende Satz.